# Can I enforce invariants in scala 3 traits?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm new to scala, so I'm curious if this is possible or if I have to use an abstract class. (I'm using scala 3 btw)

as an example I'm making a trivial model of a battery:

```
trait Chargeable(capacity: Double) {
    val capacity = capacity
    val charge: Double
}
```

of course, a battery can't hold more than its capacity so I'd like this code to error:

```
final case class BigBattery(charge: Double) extends Chargeable(9000)
BigBattery(9001) //throws Exception
```

so is there a way to get this or a similar result using traits? or are abstract classes the only way to do invariants like this?

Comment: Might be a job for https://github.com/fthomas/refined

Comment: Actually, the link I just posted is for enforcing that kind of thing at compile-time. If you want to throw an exception, you can just do so in the constructor (i.e. the body of the class/trait)

Comment: oh snap you can execute statements inside a trait definition's body? yeah that solves my problem lol

Comment: You can still use something like `require(capacity <= 9000, "battery cannot have more than 9000")` inside the trait, but this works only at runtime. It won't work at compile-time.

Comment: Perhaps you could use something from the `scala.compiletime.ops` package?